# Weird Behaviour of console - logs arrays when website is loaded for the first time only

Tags: javascript, arrays, console, append

Hello to every one of you,

I work on a simple project, and javascript's job is:

1. getting data from twitch (with jsonp) multiple times using for loop, add the necessary html and push it to an array.
2. When the loop is done all the prearranged html in the array I want to add to the website, again using for loops (there are three of them - because there are three arrays) like this below):

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < newItemBoxOn.length; i++) {
    $("#container").append(newItemBoxOn[i]); 
       }
   ```

But it didn't work. So i tried to console.log all three arrays.
I noticed different behaviour of the console when i loaded the whole website (here's what i got):
[image]

As you see, there are all three arrays in the console. But, when i refreshed the website I got three empty(!) arrays.

[image]

1.Why did that happen?
2. How to append the arrays' values to the website correctly?

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/RycerzPegaza/pen/AXRdGa

In adance, Thank you so much for good advice, i hope i described the problem well

Comment: `console.log()` calls are outside of `$.getJSON()` calls; `$.getJSON()` returns results asynchronously

Comment: This is because $.getJson is an async operation. Your console.logs are being printed first when your page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: So i can't store the properties values outside and append them to the website outside the $.getJSON()? Now i know that console.log won't catch it, but the important thing to me here is - i don't know how to append the stuff to the html correctly

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
    var channelsArr = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "comster404", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "brunofin", "storbeck", "sheevergaming", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "terakilobyte", "syndicate", "pewdiepie", "riotgames"];
    var newItemBoxClosed = [];
    var newItemBoxOn = [];
    var newItemBoxOff = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < channelsArr.length; i++) {
      var currentLink = link + channelsArr[i] + "?callback=?";
      $.getJSON(currentLink, function(data) {
          // do something with the data;
          if (data.status === 422) {
            newItemBoxClosed.push("<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><div class='cross'></div><img src=''></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-red'><p>off</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'></div><div class='userstatus'>channel closed</div></div>");
          }
          // item-box massive production
          else {
            $.getJSON(data["_links"].channel + "?callback=?", function(channelData) {
                // if data.stream === null - there's no streaming
                if (data.stream === null) {
                  newItemBoxOff.push("<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><img src='" + channelData.logo + "'></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-red'><p>off</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'>" + channelData.display_name + "</div><div class='userstatus'>offline</div></div>");
                }
                // if data.stream !== null - stream is live
                else {
                  newItemBoxOn.push("<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><img src='" + channelData.logo + "'></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-green'><p>on</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'>" + channelData.display_name + "</div><div class='userstatus'>" + channelData.game + ": " + channelData.status + "</div></div>");
                }
                newItemBoxOn.forEach(function(item) {
                  $(container).append($(item));
                });

              }) // end inner json
          }
        }) // end  getJSON
    } // end for loop

  }) // end ready
```

```css
/* colorset: 
grey - #D1D1D1;
purple - #6441A5;
*/

/*don't know if media queries needed if i have flexbox */

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 99%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 570px) {
  #switch {
    transform: translateX(5%);
  }
}
/* fonts */

body {
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  color: #6441A5;
}
#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 6px 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}
#switch {
  height: 36px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  transform: translate(24%, 6%);
  font-family: 'Bungee Shade';
  font-size: 0.77em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444;
}
#switch-on,
#switch-on:active {
  width: 48%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #44C947;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #555;
}
#switch-on:active {
  background: #33B836;
  transform: translate(2%, 4%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}
#switch-off,
#switch-off:active {
  width: 48%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #E02443;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #555;
}
#switch-off:active {
  background: #D01332;
  transform: translate(2%, 4%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}
#title-bar {
  width: 329px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  margin: 1px auto 4px;
  transform: translateX(-1px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  position: relative;
}
.item-box {
  width: 160px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 5px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 5px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.profile-img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 50% 2%, 75% 15%, 95% 50%, 82% 80%, 70% 90%, 25% 93%, 4% 60%, 5% 37%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.status-light {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(95px, 1px);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
}
p {
  font-size: 0.62em;
  line-height: 32px;
  transform: translate(-4px, 2px);
  font-family: 'Bungee Shade';
}
#light-red {
  background: #E02443;
}
#light-green {
  background: #44C947;
}
.username,
.userstatus {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1px auto;
  color: #6441A5;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 78px);
  padding: 2px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.reflection {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 10%, 50% 2%, 75% 15%, 95% 50%, 82% 80%, 70% 70%, 75% 100%, 10% 79%, 5% 75%, 2% 60%, 4% 72%, 0% 45%, 0% 40%, 4% 34%);
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(100, 65, 165, 0.12);
  transform: translate(0px, -50px);
}
.username {
  border: 1px solid #6441A5;
}
.userstatus {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px black;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Shade';
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-13px);
}
/*** red cros ***/

.cross {
  position: absolute;
  right: 68px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.cross:before,
.cross:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 105px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #E02443;
}
.cross:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cross:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="switch">
      <div id="switch-on">on</div>
      <div id="switch-off">off</div>
    </div>
    <div id="title-bar">
      <h1>twitch observer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <!-- container start -->


  </div>
  <!-- container end -->
</body>
```

You're doing an asynchronous call to the web services. This is exactly why the second JSON call is nested within the first. I changed your JavaScript to place the `console.log()` calls inside and then get lots of valid HTML, similar to this:

```
["<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-…div class='userstatus'>channel closed</div></div>", "<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-…div class='userstatus'>channel closed</div></div>"]
0
:
"<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><div class='cross'></div><img src=''></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-red'><p>off</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'></div><div class='userstatus'>channel closed</div></div>"
1
:
"<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><div class='cross'></div><img src=''></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-red'><p>off</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'></div><div class='userstatus'>channel closed</div></div>"
length
:
2
```

**Edit:**
To actually insert that HTML into the container `div`, you would iterate the array inside the second JSON call:

```
newItemBoxOn.forEach(function (item) {
  $(container).append($(item));
});
```

Comment: I can see those array elements too, but is it possible to append these values to the html outside of the $.getJSON? Because i tried to for loop it and append every single array element, but i couldn't

Comment: That won't work, because the code isn't sequential. You need to append it within that inner call's callback function.

Comment: @Sebastian I edited my answer to include the working snippet.

Answer (score 0):

An approach substituting `$.when()`, `.then()`, `Function.prototype.apply()` for `for` loop

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
    var channelsArr = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "comster404", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "brunofin", "storbeck", "sheevergaming", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "terakilobyte", "syndicate", "pewdiepie", "riotgames"];
    var newItemBoxClosed = [];
    var newItemBoxOn = [];
    var newItemBoxOff = [];
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    // for (var i = 0; i < channelsArr.length; i++) {
    $.when.apply($, $.map(channelsArr, function(_, i) { 
      var currentLink = link + channelsArr[i] + "?callback=?";
      return $.getJSON(currentLink, function(data) {
          // do something with the data;
          if (data.status === 422) {
            newItemBoxClosed.push("<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><div class='cross'></div><img src=''></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-red'><p>off</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'></div><div class='userstatus'>channel closed</div></div>");
          }
          // item-box massive production
          else {
            return $.getJSON(data["_links"].channel + "?callback=?", function(channelData) {
                // if data.stream === null - there's no streaming
                if (data.stream === null) {
                  newItemBoxOff.push("<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><img src='" + channelData.logo + "'></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-red'><p>off</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'>" + channelData.display_name + "</div><div class='userstatus'>offline</div></div>");
                }
                // if data.stream !== null - stream is live
                else {
                  newItemBoxOn.push("<div class='item-box'><ul><li><div class='profile-img'><img src='" + channelData.logo + "'></div></li><li><div class='status-light' id='light-green'><p>on</p></div></li></ul><div class='reflection'></div><div class='username'>" + channelData.display_name + "</div><div class='userstatus'>" + channelData.game + ": " + channelData.status + "</div></div>");
                }

              }) // end inner json
          }
        })
        // end  getJSON
    })) // end for loop
    .then(function(data) {
      $("body").append(newItemBoxOn, newItemBoxOff, newItemBoxClosed)
    })
  }) // end ready
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/hlquTnwurSuN2SxnT0UI?p=preview

Comment: Your version appends multiple times the same values somehow.(you can see it in your plnkr, just take a look on the same avatars multiple times). I tried this :   if (i === (channelsArr.length-1))
 {
  for (var j = 0; j < newItemBoxOff.length; j++)
   { $("#container").append(newItemBoxOff[j]); 
   }
 
 }    // But without a success

Comment: I see, but.  it loads only the values from the array "newItemBoxClosed". Most certainly becuase it's the only array that doesn't contain any ajax data. I tried for an hour to solve it, but without a success. I can't make it show all three arrays.

Comment: There does not appear to be a `streams ` property at `data` object?